# Accessing subdomain via IP address on apache server

Tags: wordpress

I have installed WordPress on a subdomain that currently resides on an unpropogated domain. (It can only be accessed via IP address.) Is it possible for me to access any subdomains that have been created, eg: subdomain.mysite.com/wp-admin via IP, or do I have to wait till the domain has been propogated?

This is my first question, I apoligize if I have not explained my self thoroughly enough. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `http://[IP]/~[username]/[domain.tld]/` to access your site by IP.

Where `[IP]` is the IP of your server and `[username]` is your username for the hosting site. `[domain.tld]` is the name of the folder on which you have mapped your subdomain.

Comment: Pretty sure this only works if cPanel is on the server. But most servers have this so it's worth giving it a go ;)

Comment: Yes, since OP *seems* to be a beginner, it's fair to assume he's using cPanel.

Comment: Haha yes I am quite new to the Web game but I sure am loving it.

Comment: Did it work? Don't forget to accept the answer that worked for you.

Comment: @RRikesh hii, its not working for me... I want to access imitix.com using the same method. The IP address shown in my cpanel is 208.91.198.220 and my username for my cPanel is imitix. Could you please tell me how can I access it using IP address?

Comment: Contact your host for help. They will surely sort it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to check it with an anonymous proxy?

I use http://anonymouse.org/anonwww.html to check sites as in Australia it normally takes a little longer to propagate over to here.

**Please note:** You will only be able to check it's existence, you would not use this to make site modifications through the back end. That would best be done once the domain propagates.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I managed to get hold of our service provider, for some reason its still pointing to the old domain but they are resolving the issue. I am just doing the content locally now so when they get it fixed I can upload. Thanks again

Comment: No worries. It can be quite a pain waiting for domains to resolve ;)